# index.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText') at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.js:66)

Tags: javascript, web

I was trying to create a drumstick website as a part of #javascript30 challenge, but I am getting the following error:

> index.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText') at HTMLDivElement. (index.js:66)

```js
function playAudio(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 's':
    case 'S':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'd':
    case 'D':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'f':
    case 'F':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'g':
    case 'G':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'h':
    case 'H':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'j':
    case 'J':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'k':
    case 'K':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;

    case 'l':
    case 'L':
      var clap = new Audio("sounds/clap.wav");
      clap.play();
      break;
    default:
      console.log(key);
  }
}

// To produce sound when the drum is CLICKED
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".key").length; ++i) {
  // console.log(i);

  document.querySelectorAll(".key")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var keyPress = document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[i].innerText; //  !!problem in this line!!
    playAudio(keyPress);
    buttonAnimation(keyPress);
  });

}

// To produce sound when the drum key is pressed
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { //call back funtion passes back evt obj
  playAudio(event.key);
  buttonAnimation(event.key);
});



function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {
  try {
    document.querySelector("." + currentKey.toUpperCase()).classList.add("playing");
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("." + currentKey.toUpperCase()).classList.remove("playing");
    }, 100);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }

}

for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".key").length; ++i) {
  // console.log(i);

  document.querySelectorAll(".key")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var keyPress = document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[i].innerText; //  !!problem in this line!!
    playAudio(keyPress);
    buttonAnimation(keyPress);
  });

}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div class="A key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>
  <div class="S key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="D key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>
  <div class="F key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">openhat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="G key">
    <kbd>G</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
  <div class="H key">
    <kbd>H</kbd>
    <span class="sound">ride</span>
  </div>
  <div class="J key">
    <kbd>J</kbd>
    <span class="sound">snare</span>
  </div>
  <div class="K key">
    <kbd>K</kbd>
    <span class="sound">tom</span>
  </div>
  <div class="L key">
    <kbd>L</kbd>
    <span class="sound">tink</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with trying to iterate over the nodelist given by `querySelectorAll` *twice*, adding all those listeners to the elements in a loop, and then trying to pick up the `kbd` element using that index.

Instead of attaching all those listeners use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and attach *one* listener to the `.keys` element.

You can then find the text of the previous tag (note that [we use previousSibling twice here because of the whitespace in the HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), and log that.

Here's a reduced example of your code.

```js
function playAudio(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

const keys = document.querySelector('.keys');
keys.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const kbd = e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling;
  const key = kbd.textContent;
  playAudio(key);
}
```

```css
.key { cursor: pointer; }
.key:hover { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div class="A key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>
  <div class="S key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="D key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>
  <div class="F key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">openhat</span>
  </div>
  <div class="G key">
    <kbd>G</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I add the eventListener to "keys" class, it would also target the container around. Also, could you please elaborate this statement:"I think the issue is with trying to iterate over the nodelist given by querySelectorAll twice, adding all those listeners to the elements in a loop, and then trying to pick up the kbd element using that index."

Comment: Also, I have used this process to build another drumstick website, but in that website, I wasn't using the <kbd> tag. Could this tag be the one creating the problem.